# How can i repeat in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, coordinates, jsfiddle

I have a simple question but it's difficult to explain it..Please help me!! I have a script in a JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/irinikonsta/b4t9hspj/

In this script, the program reads a simple txt (with coordinates and an id for each pair of coordinates) and it transforms into an array. After that, it begins a repeat for each pair of coordinates: ( text["features"].forEach(function(feature) {....)

In this repeat, it is calculated a simple sky's percentage. This sky's percentage is the varriable "per". I want this varriable "per" to be saved in a varriable "z" in the array's attributes. This varriable z exists if you go to the console->object->features->0->attributes. But if you see in the 0 point,1 point,etc this varriable doesn't change according to its coordinates. Do you know why? i attach to you the txt file because you have to upload it from your own. Please help me its very important..Thank you so much have a nice day! The txt file:

```
{
"displayFieldName": "",
"fieldAliases": {
    "FID": "FID",
    "Id": "Id",
    "Longtitude": "Longtitude",
    "Latitude": "Latitude"
},
"geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
"spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 4326,
    "latestWkid": 4326
},
"fields": [{
    "name": "FID",
    "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
    "alias": "FID"
}, {
    "name": "Id",
    "type": "esriFieldTypeInteger",
    "alias": "Id"
}, {
    "name": "Longtitude",
    "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
    "alias": "Longtitude"
}, {
    "name": "Latitude",
    "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
    "alias": "Latitude"
}],
"features": [{
    "attributes": {
        "FID": 0,
        "Id": 1,
        "Longtitude": 23.739000000000001,
        "Latitude": 37.972000000000001
    },
    "geometry": {
        "x": 23.739000000000001,
        "y": 37.972000000000001
    }
}, {
    "attributes": {
        "FID": 1,
        "Id": 2,
        "Longtitude": 23.760100000000001,
        "Latitude": 37.984999999999999
    },
    "geometry": {
        "x": 23.760100000000001,
        "y": 37.984999999999999
    }
}, {
    "attributes": {
        "FID": 2,
        "Id": 3,
        "Longtitude": 23.749199999999998,
        "Latitude": 37.975999999999999
    },
    "geometry": {
        "x": 23.749199999999998,
        "y": 37.975999999999999
    }
}, {
    "attributes": {
        "FID": 3,
        "Id": 4,
        "Longtitude": 23.735700000000001,
        "Latitude": 37.975999999999999
    },
    "geometry": {
        "x": 23.735700000000001,
        "y": 37.975999999999999
    }
}]
}
```

Comment: well if you check your console logs the value always is `98.1466` for every object, so why do you expect a changed value on each `z` of the features?

Comment: yes this exactly what i dont want.. i mean it should take every single pair of coordinates with this statement: text["features"].forEach(function(feature) {...    and ultimatelly, it should have  another result (z) for every pair of coordinates..

Comment: but it doesnt.. :( @alex-rokabilis

Comment: the problem for this is that your algorithm inside `getBase64FromImageUrl` always produces the same values :) check your logs and you will see that when the google maps url changes all the other variables that you calculate are the same! I am not sure what you calculate and I cant help with this!

Comment: btw, ti ftiaxneis re patriotisa?! :)

Comment: @alex-rokabilis yes it's a little difficult to explain what i am calculating.. :p (the main purpose is to calculate a sky's percentage) ...it sounds like when the googleapis takes this statement:   let myString1 = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=${x},${y}&size=300x300&pitch=90`... it doesn't understand x and y as each pair or longtitude and latitude..  the process after that is very specific and there shouldnt be mistakes there.. anyway thank you so much for your time :) ...

Comment: hello file mou!prospatho na ipologiso ena pososto tou ouranou gia ena sigkekrimeno kommati tis polutexnioupolis.. kai gia kathe simeio pou tou dino apo to txt eprepe na mou ipologizei kai na mou apothikeuei auto to pososto san z..

Comment: alla mallon dn katalavainei oti prepei na allazei to x kai to y se auti tin entoli tou google apis.. ax ase ti travao!! se euxaristo para ola auta gia to xrono sou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you need to understand, is that you want to run an asynchronous operation (the download of the image from gmaps) inside a synchronous operation (forEach). You can achieve this with various ways, in my code I used [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), the logic is that I run the async operations in parallel and when each one completes I get the result and put it in the array.

But the main problem is that somehow your data is wrong. All the links that you created are pointing in that [image](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=23.7601,37.985&size=300x300&pitch=90). Yeah no image...

The coordinates you have are pointing in the middle of the sea! [Check for your self](https://www.google.gr/maps/place/23%C2%B045'36.4%22N+37%C2%B059'06.0%22E/@23.7601,37.9828113,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d23.7601!4d37.985)

But if you swap them with

`let y = feature["attributes"].Longtitude;
let x = feature["attributes"].Latitude;`

Now these coordinates point to the middle of Athens :)

```js
function getBase64FromImageUrl(url, callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  var range = 60;
  var finalZ;
  img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

  img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


    //console.log("imageData",imageData);
    //var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var index = (150 * imageData.width + 150) * 4;
    var red = imageData.data[index];
    var green = imageData.data[index + 1];
    var blue = imageData.data[index + 2];
    var alpha = imageData.data[index + 3];
    console.log(red);
    console.log(green);
    console.log(blue);
    var rangedRB = red - range;
    var rangedGB = green - range;
    var rangedBB = blue - range;

    var rangedRT = red + range;
    var rangedGT = green + range;
    var rangedBT = blue + range;

    var data = imageData.data;
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
      var red1 = data[i];
      var green1 = data[i + 1];
      var blue1 = data[i + 2];
      if ((red1 < rangedRT && red1 > rangedRB) && (green1 < rangedGT && green1 > rangedGB) && (blue1 < rangedBT && blue1 > rangedBB)) {
        counter = counter + 1;
        var p = data.length / 4;
        var pe = counter / p;
        var per = pe * 100;
        finalZ = per;
      }
    }
    console.log(url);
    console.log("counterFinal", counter);
    console.log("data.length", data.length / 4);
    console.log("percentage:", (counter / (data.length / 4)) * 100);

    //console.log(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));
    // alert(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));

    callback(finalZ);
  };

  img.src = url;
}

function openFile(event) {
  console.log('openfile', event);
  var input = event.target;

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var text = JSON.parse(reader.result);
    console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));

    var results = 0;
    text["features"].forEach(function(feature) {

      //y is the Longtitude
      //x is the Latitude
      //because data are wrong!
      let y = feature["attributes"].Longtitude;
      let x = feature["attributes"].Latitude;

      let myString1 = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=${x},${y}&size=300x300&pitch=90`;
      getBase64FromImageUrl(myString1, function(finalZ) {
        feature["attributes"].z = finalZ;
        results++;
        if (results == text["features"].length) {
          console.log(text);
        }
      });



    });


  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'>
<br>
<img id='output'>
```

Comment: Hi @alex-rokabilis! i tried this here with run code snippet and it was exactly what i needed! but when i try it in jsddle, itsn;t working.. do you know why?? :) *Thaaaaank you sooo much!!!!   https://jsfiddle.net/irinikonsta/2qk8cu4q/1/

Comment: also, when i try this i dont see any z in this array :( (omg what i did with coordinates :D)

Answer (score 0):

Use `For Each` or `for` Loop to repeat Array in **Javascript**

```
for each (variable in object) {
    // statement(s) to run
}
```

There are 4 looping statements in **Javascipt** : `For`, `foreach`, `while`, `do while`. And recursion!

Comment: you mean where?? :p @Sddharth panchal

Comment: i am doing this i dont know if you mean that:   
           text["features"].forEach(function(feature) {....

Comment: Between Script Tag... like this
var sum = 0;
var obj = {prop1: 5, prop2: 13, prop3: 8};

for each (var item in obj) {
  sum += item;
}

console.log(sum);

Comment: there are also 4 looping statement in javascipt which is use to repeat your array element, 'For', 'foreach', 'while', 'do while'.

Comment: My array element doesn't repeat like this?     text["features"].forEach(function(feature) {...

Comment: function fillArray(value, len) {
  if (len == 0) return [];
  var a = [value];
  while (a.length * 2 <= len) a = a.concat(a);
  if (a.length < len) a = a.concat(a.slice(0, len - a.length));
  return a;
}